# Uncatchable exception using TextureView

Tags: android

Hello I am facing problem with texturevideoview.When i click back button at that time sometimes texturevideoview crash with this log.

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.destroyHardwareResources()' on a null object reference**

Please help me.

Comment: a Nullpointer exception is definetely a result of a wrong implementation. You haven´t initialized an object and this must not be catched, this must be avoided. so to help, we need to see your relevant part of code.

Comment: Hey i am initializing object,its working proper when you play video,but if video is playing and you pressed back button than it is crashing.

Comment: Something must be wrong here, any wrong implementation or something else, so please show Your code. Otherwise you can´t get help....

Comment: hey Opiatefuchs can you please give me your email,So i can send you my code.